# Removing portion of a file path

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am very much new to scripting, so apologies if this sounds unclear.

I have a file path that I wan to cut up using sed:

The file path can look similar to:

```
/to/be/removed/dir1a/keep/this/part
/to/be/removed/dir2b/keep/this/part
/to/be/removed/random/keep/this/part
```

I want to make sure, regardless of which format I get, I always end up with:

```
/keep/this/partRestored
```

I have found similar examples but I cannot make them work with the above specifications.

***EDIT***

Sorry the original template of the question was not too clear. Sorry for wasting your time.
I basically search for the latest version of a file in the.
The result can be in any of the following form:

```
/home/backup/dir1/destination/file
/home/backup/dir2/destination2/file
/home/backup/folder/destination3/file
```

In other word, I always want to remove anything before the *dir1*, *dir2* or *folder*.
AND append *restore* to the end of whats left.
I hope this is more clear. Thanks for your help.

Comment: the examples is too general. please provide relevant examples

Comment: What's the rule? Keep the last 3 parts of the path? Remove the first 4? Does it depend on the pattern? Please be more specific.

Comment: is "keep/this/part" always the same? Better examples please

Comment: sorry @nu11p01n73R and the rest. I edited the question. I hope it makes more sense. I'm really new at this.

Comment: @SSF_curious Its fine. only when the question is clear that others can help you :)

Comment: It is still not clear. Provide a more general sample input together with a desired output. How would you explain the solution in words? "remove everything up to 3rd word? remove everything until dir1 is found?"

Comment: keep everything after the word that contains'dir1' or 'dir2' or 'folder' (excluding the words that contain 'dir1','dir2', 'folder'). I hope that is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
 sed -r  's#.*/(dir1|dir2|folder)(/.*$)#\2/restore#g'
```

Test:

```
sed -r  's#.*/(dir1|dir2|folder)(/.*$)#\2/restore#g' input
/destination/file/restore
/destination2/file/restore
/destination3/file/restore
```

**EDIT**

To be more specific

```
sed -r  's#.*/(dir1|dir2|folder)[^/]*(/.*$)#\2/restore#g'
```

Test:

```
$ echo "/home/backup/dir1_a/destination/file" | sed -r  's#.*/(dir1|dir2|folder)[^/]*(/.*$)#\2/restore#g'
/destination/file/restore
```

Comment: what if there are other characters after dir1, dir2 and folder? for example:
/home/backup/dir1_a/destination/file
/home/backup/dir2_b/destination2/file
/home/backup/folder_c/destination3/file

Comment: Fantastic. That did the trick. sorry again for making it unclear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `basename` and `dirname`:

```
f=/home/backup/dir1/destination/file
echo /$(basename $(dirname $f))/$(basename $f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing/changing root part: `/to/be/removed/dir1a/keep/this/part`

- always same root

  `sed 's#^/to/be/removed/#/NewPathYouWantAsRoot/#' InputFile`
- always same root depth (in this sample, depth = 3)

  `sed 's#\(/[^/]*\)\{3\}/#/NewPathYouWantAsRoot/#' InputFile`

---

adding the `/keep/this/partRestored` (take also path with `/` as last char, like a folder)

```
sed 's#/\{0,1\}$#/keep/this/partRestored#' InputFile
```

---

Any combination of those could be used, just separate the action by `;`. Ex:

```
sed 's#\(/[^/]*\)\{3\}/#/NewPathYouWantAsRoot/#;s#/\{0,1\}$#/keep/this/partRestored#' InputFile
```